# prettyPhoto loading, but not working (not callable)

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

### Solved

With the amount of information I provided this was unsolvable. A PHP library that I'm using was also including jQuery, resulting in double inclusion and prettyPhoto going berzerk.

### The problem

This is starting to drive me crazy. I've included jQuery 1.7, prettyPhoto 3.1 and my own JS file:

```
<script src="/files/js/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/files/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/m/js/jzg.js?cache=no" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

No errors appear in the console, unless I try to use prettyPhoto - then I get the `$("mySelectorGoesHere").prettyPhoto is not a function` error.

In FireBug console `jQuery.prettyPhoto` and `$.prettyPhoto` both show up as `undefined`.

I can inspect the header of the page to see that the `script` tags show proper content of the included files. The same is seen in the Network tab - files seem to get loaded OK.

I've tried appending an alert to `jquery.prettyPhoto.js` and on page load the alert fires up, but prettyPhoto itself still is undefined.

One more thing I tried was to download the latest versions of prettyPhoto (3.1.3) and jQuery (1.7.1) and replace the ones I was using - to no effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: try looking for errors in Error Console. You can open up error console by Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: Thanks. Apart from loads of css warnings, there is only one JS warning regarding the use of deprecated getAttributeNodeNS(). I presume it's part of jQuery or prettyPhoto. And then there's the single error I mentioned in my post (prettyPhoto is not a function). And that is all

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, and in a day or two you'll be able to accept it

Comment: Yea, I know, but I have to wait until 8 hours from original posting before I can even submit the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the amount of information I provided this was unsolvable. A PHP library that I'm using was also including jQuery, resulting in double inclusion and prettyPhoto going berzerk.